# R: ggplot: two plots in one dataframe: color one plot only when it is less than the other plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar, geom-point

I have two geom_point plots from a single dataframe on a plot. What I want is to only color label when plot 2 is below plot 1 on the y axis. So if it is above, plot2 would be grey/black, when it is below, it will be labeled by a certain column in the dataframe

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(c("2022-07-29 00:00:00","2022-07-29 00:00:05",
                           "2022-07-29 00:05:00","2022-07-29 00:05:05",
                           "2022-07-29 00:10:00","2022-07-29 00:15:00",
                           "2022-07-29 00:20:00","2022-07-29 00:20:05"), 
                          c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                          c(0.8,2.1,2.5,4.1,5,6.1,6.9,8.1),
                          c("a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c")),
                          c("timeStamp", "value1", "value2", "text"))
```

So the closest graph I can come up with is

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(timeStamp,value1))+
geom_point(aes(timeStamp, value2, color=value2>value1)) +
scale_color_manual(name="callout", values = setNames(c('green','red'), c(T,F)))
```

This plot is almost exactly what I need, but I want the red line that is below the first plot to use the text column to label. If i changed the setNames above to c('green', text), I thought it should work but doesn't and cant figure out the correct way forward. Thank you

Comment: Please could you double check the supplied code to make sure it runs without error.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: it still doesn't run

Comment: Edits didn't copy correctly, it now definitely runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of what you want. The key line is

```
callout <- factor(ifelse(df$value2 > df$value1, NA, df$text))
```

which sets a colour to the text column if value2 is less than value1.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <-
    setNames(data.frame(
        as.POSIXct(
            c(
            "2022-07-29 00:00:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:00:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:10:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:15:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:05"
            )),
        c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
        c(0.8, 2.1, 2.5, 4.1, 5, 6.1, 6.9, 8.1),
        c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c")
    ),
    c("timeStamp", "value1", "value2", "text"))

# this works out the colours
callout <- factor(ifelse(df$value2 > df$value1, NA, df$text))

gg2 <- 
    ggplot(df) + 
    geom_point(aes(timeStamp,value1), col='grey50', size=3) + 
    geom_point(aes(timeStamp, value2, color = callout), size=3) 

gg2
```

[image]

I also added the `as.POSIXct()` call which makes the x axis neater.